# How to combine this PHP code with HTML and Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, html

for example, this is my PHP code:

```
<?php

if($country_code == 'US')
{
        header('Location: http://www.test.com');
}

else 
{
        header('Location: http://www.test.com/');
}

?>
```

I'm trying to use a Javascript code for tracking, it has to be above the `</body>` tag.

I have tried different ways of combining the `PHP` code with `HTML`, I have tried placing the HTML separately below the `PHP` also, one example:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <?php

     ?>
<script></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The furthest I got was, it tracked the click but it didn't redirect giving me this error:

```
`Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by`
```

Will appreciate any suggestions and help, thank you!

Comment: You can't use php's `header` if you've already started to output the document, you'd have to use a different method for the redirect (i.e. JavaScript's `window.location.href`).

Comment: PHP works in order from top to bottom in a sense. Once the DOM starts to render content, PHP can't just stop, reverse, place your header, then rebuild, if that makes sense =] Put that PHP at the top of the page, then work from there.

Comment: Are you trying to redirect the page based on the variable $country_code? Or are you trying to do something else?

Comment: Yes, trying to redirect the page and track it using a Javascript code.

Comment: Where does `$country_code` come from?

Answer (score 1):

Put the php redirect code at the begining of your document before anything is outputted. Check for spaces after the `?>` tag and before the `<?php` tag because these will be printed out and the response header will be sent therefor you will not be able to modify the header to redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You have to try something like the following to track:

```
<?php

if($country_code == 'US')
{
        header('Location: http://www.test.com/?us=yes');
}

else 
{
        header('Location: http://www.test.com/?us=no');
}

?>
```

And then in your index page check for the value of the us parameter. Also you should **Notice** that there is no any output should be printed before the header function to void the warning :

> `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by`

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is that PHP run before JavaScript. So you need to geet the PHP variable inside a JavaScript.

```
<?php
// your normal code here, like connection to DB
?>

<script>var test = <?php> echo $thatVariable; <?> </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may not send an output to the client before a header() tag of php. 
So you can generate a redirect page which gets the country information via js and send it to the php (using e.g form submit). after that you can redirect to the accoording page via php header()

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if($country_code === 'US'){

   echo "<script> window.location.href='http://www.test.com1'</script>";

}
else{

   echo "<script>  window.location.href='http://www.test.com2/'</script>";

 }

?>
```